# Remove default spacing/padding on HTML table for email signature in Gmail iPhone app

Tags: html, email, signature

Any advice on how to remove the default padding/spacing that seems to be applied to the tables by the Gmail iPhone App which is drastically affecting the design layout. Looks perfect in Outlook, MacBook App, Gmail online etc. But on Gmail iPhone app, I'm getting this. (see attached).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBk0z.jpg)

Comment: Would you please present your html codes